# How do I write a Windows batch script to copy the newest file from a directory into new folder?

Tags: windows, date, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I need to move, cut & paste, the newest file in a directory to a newly created folder location. The file is created by a separate program that I do not have permissions. The new directory location is created by a batch file which has been copied below. I found some basis to follow from code samples. I'm just having a bit of trouble putting the pieces together. How do I move the newest file from a directory location to new directory location?

```
:: Auto directory date batch (MMDDYYYY format)
:: First parses month, day, and year into mm , dd, yyyy formats and then combines to be DDMMYYYY
:: Setups %date% variable
:: @author Deepu Mohan Puthrote www.deepumohan.com
@echo off
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET date=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%
echo New folder name %date%
MKDIR %date%
```

I added to first .bat to move file to new directory, as my attempt to move the file to the new directory but I got an error

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR . /B /O:-D') DO COPY %%I <<%date%>>
pause
```

<< unexpected at this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with your `FOR` loop.  You'll just want to do a `MOVE` rather than `COPY`, and then quit the loop after processing the first item.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR . /B /O:-D /A-D') DO (
    MOVE "%%I" "%date%"
    GOTO :EOF
)
```

I've added `/A-D` in the `DIR` to exclude directories, and removed the `<<` and `>>`. (I'm not sure why those were in there to begin with.)

Comment: I am not sure if this should be a new question or not, but what would need to change if I wanted to grab all the files of the current date to this directory, instead of just the newest file.

Comment: Ah, that's actually easier!  :-)  Robocopy is your friend.  Robocopy is included in Vista and newer, and is available for download for older OSes.  `robocopy "from\dir" "to\dir" /maxage:1 /mov` will move all files that are one day old.  Type `robocopy /?` for help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /od /b /a-d') do set "file=%%~i"
move "%file%" "%date%"
```

BTW: do not use default environment variable names for batch variables (date).